# Why my HTML sections are not aligned beside each other?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to align two sections of a website i'm building from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5HFXcJjt7Y

This is what the site from my end looks like currently:
[image: This is what the site from my end looks like currently]

The blue section sits fine however, the cards with "UX/UI Design" "Digital Marketing" "Web Development" & "Content Writing" are not aligned next to the section "Exprienced UX/UI Designer".

This is what my HTML currently looks like, both sections are wrapped around with a class of "landing".

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Jono Mackay</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
      <body>
        <div class="detail-lines">
          <div class="left-line-1"></div>
          <div class="left-line-2"></div>
          <div class="left-line-3"></div>
          <div class="center-line"></div>
          <div class="right-line-1"></div>
          <div class="right-line-2"></div>
          <div class="right-line-3"></div>
        </div>

          <nav>
              <a href="#" class="logo"><div class="rec"></div>Jono Mackay</a>
              <div class="nav-right">
                <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
                <a href="#">Work<img src="images/icon-work.png" alt="work icon"></a>
              </div>
          </nav>

        <div class="wrapper-content">
              <div class="landing">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <h1>Exprienced UX/UI<br>Designer</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore perferendis porro assumenda repellendus laboriosam!<br><br>Adipisci repellat eligendi reprehenderit maiores ab, asperiores reiciendis quo accusamus.</p>
                    <div class="rec-large"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="skills">
                      <div class="skill-box">
                        <h2>UX/UI Design</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skill-box">
                        <h2>Digital Marketing</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skill-box">
                        <h2>Web Development</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skill-box">
                        <h2>Content Writing</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="section2">
                <div class="left r">
                  <img class="arrow" src="images/icon-arrow.png" alt="arrow icon">
                  <h1 class="white">LET'S START A <br>PROJECT</h1>
                  <div class="rec-large-2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right l">
                  <div class="line2"></div>
                  <h1>DESIGN &amp;<br>DEVELOPMENT</h1>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore perferendis porro assumenda repellendus laboriosam!<br><br>Adipisci repellat eligendi reprehenderit maiores ab, asperiores reiciendis quo accusamus.</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <div class="social">
            <a href="#">Youtube</a>
            <a href="#">Instagram</a>
            <a href="#">Twitter</a>
          </div>
          <p>2019&copy; Jono Mackay</p>
        </footer>
      </body>
  </html>
```

And this is what my CSS files looks like currently:

```
/*
 * ─── GLOBAL ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 */

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

:root {
  --main-black: #1f202b;
  --main-gray: #8a8ca5;
  --light-gray: #e7e7e8;
  --main-blue: #5952ff;
}

html {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: var(--main-black);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--main-black);
}

p {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--main-gray);
}
a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--main-gray);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper-content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.r {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 530px;
}

.l {
  padding-left: 200px;
}

/*
 * ─── NAV ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 5%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--main-black);
}

.nav-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50px;
}

.nav-right a > img {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}


.nav-right a:first-child {
  color: var(--main-blue);
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.rec {
  background-color: var(--main-blue);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}


/*
 * ─── CONTENT ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 */


.landing .section2 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.right p {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.left p {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.skills {
  float: right;
}


.skill-box {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 390px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(75,79,124,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(75,79,124,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(75,79,124,0.1);
}


.rec-large {
  background-color: var(--main-blue);
  height: 150px;
  width: 620px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -80px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: var(--main-black);
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -140px;
}


.line2 {
  height: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: var(--main-black);
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 60px;
}

.section2 {
  margin-top: 700px;
}

.rec-large-2 {
  background-color: var(--main-blue);
  height: 260px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -147px;
  left: -472px;
  z-index: -1;
}


.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: -100px;
}
```

the  section seems to sit outside of the "landing", even though it is showing that it is wrapped in the same section. And going through the tutorial, I don't seem to see anything that I have missed so far.

If there is any explanation to this please let me know as all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: add this line in your css flie: `.landing{display:flex;flex-direction:row;}`

Comment: also, since the tutorial for as far as i see doesn't care too much about crossbrowser compatibility, you might want to pull your css through some website like this: `https://autoprefixer.github.io/`

Comment: That seemed to have worked, thank you! Another issue I just noticed is that it's not responsive :/ I could simply add bootstrap and there won't be any issues?

Comment: Just follow the bootstrap layout (containers, cols, etc.) and it should work fine. Let us know if this doesn't (pls try first).